# How to check if someone allowed push notification on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification

I am developing a webpage where the next page depends upon whether the user allowed push notification.

When the user clicks on to allow, it should go to one page and if the user clicks on Not allow then on another.

Comment: If you found my answer correct and the solution works for you, please consider to accept my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a callback function to the notification request as follows:

`Notification.requestPermission().then(callback);`
The callback function gets a `result` parameter, the value of the result determines if the notifications were allowed, denied or dismissed.